# Geometry check, one layer should not exceed the edges of the other layer

Tags: qgis, geometry

I want to do this check in QGIS
the geometries of one layer should not exceed the edges of the other layer
example:
-buildings, the ones colored with orange
it must not exceed the edges of the plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to Topology. You can use the *Topology Checker* plugin in QGIS. You can add rules for specific layers. You can follow the plugin documentation for the rules:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html